# Put figure and table captions in margin

Tags: captions, margins, floatrow

I like the layout when figure and table captions are in the margin.
This creates a more "fluent" text.

To position the captions in the margin I use the floatrow package.
This works fine for me.
However, the package has not been updated recently.

So I wondered if there are alternatives or other ways to do this?

Comment: As far as I am aware the package does not need to be updated, although I may be wrong.

Comment: There are other ways to do this.  The marginnote package will work with floats (marginpar does not).  The tufte class specializes in this sort of thing.

Comment: Thx @PeterWilson. I guess not. No problems encountered up till now.

Comment: Thx @JohnKormylo I will have a look at marginnote. Would like to avoid to use a new document class.